# "limit" clause on joining?

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group

table1:

```
id , otherColumn, otherColumn2 ...
```

table2:

```
id, table1_id, someOtherColumns...
```

I.E. one to many relationships

A trivial join would be:

```
select * from table1 left outer join table2 on table2.table1_id=table1.id;
```

I want to do something different: for each row in table1, bring at most 1 row from table2, no matter which if there are several candidates. Just as I can limit the amount of results on a regular select

Is this possible? How?

Comment: You've been here for twelve months. Format your posts please.

Comment: (And quit writing tags in titles!)

Comment: So, @Tomalak, do you have something to contribute to the *topic* of the question?

Comment: No. That is why I did not post an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group) or http://stackoverflow.com/q/3869571/27535 This is a tricky in MySQL as it doesn't have ROW_NUMBER or CROSS APPLY

Comment: It's only a half-duplicate (although that is a crucial part of the puzzle) because this is in relationship to a join as well.

Comment: You can try modifying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233757/order-within-group-by/7234200#7234200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities:

1. Use a sub-select. This will force the inner result-set to be limited. Advantage is that grouping/aggregation operations can be used. (I am not sure what issues, if any, MySQL has with sub-selects and holistic query planning.)
2. Use a WHERE in the primary statement and let the SQL engine "do it's thing". If the WHERE can be "moved" before the join, a smart engine will do so as it will result in less rows being processed. I *think* this is part of the basic Relational Algebra model (for *independent* records), but I am not sure. Look at the query plan. (I do not use MySQL, so I do know what optimizations are done.)

And, as always, verify results and run performance tests if it matters.

Happy coding.